# Add a WHERE clause to a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL query that works really well. What it's doing is displaying all the filenames `(filename)` in a database, along with the poster of that filename and then any user who is tagged with that filename `(cp.user_id)`. Later on in the script I explode the `tagGroup.`

I have a created a new field in the `tbl_collab` table called 'approved' which can either be `'yes'` or `'no'` and I want to know how to add a WHERE clause to my query so only the users where approved="yes" in tbl_collab are displayed. How can I do this? Many thanks.

```
"SELECT up.id, up.file, up.title, p.user_name, p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id, '~', cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC LIMIT ? , ?"
```

This is how I am exploding the `tagGroup`.

```
$tag_array = explode('|' , $tagGroup);

foreach($tag_array as $tag) {

list($uid,$uname) = explode('~',$tag,2);
```

Comment: Add `WHERE c.approved = 'yes'` below the final `LEFT JOIN` but _before_ your `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this condition in where clause like

```
"SELECT up.id, up.file, up.title, p.user_name, p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id, '~', cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
WHERE c.approved = 'yes'
GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC LIMIT ? , ?"
```

Or you can add this condition in joining condition like

```
"SELECT up.id, up.file, up.title, p.user_name, p.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cp.user_id, '~', cp.user_name) SEPARATOR '|') AS tagGroup
FROM tbl_uploads up
LEFT JOIN tbl_users p ON up.user_id = p.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON up.file = c.file AND c.approved = 'yes'
LEFT JOIN tbl_users cp ON cp.user_id = c.collab_userid
GROUP BY up.file ORDER BY up.id DESC LIMIT ? , ?"
```

Comment: I went for the second condition in the end as it worked the best for my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add `WHERE c.approved = 'yes'`to your sql query ;) or change the JOIN-condition to `LEFT JOIN tbl_collab c ON (up.file = c.file AND c.approved = 'yes')`